# C# Sorting element inside an array

Tags: c#, sorting

I'm trying to do a sorting for my result.

Eg: `result = 04,07,01,57,83,39` Expect: `result = 01,04,07,39,57,83`

I have been try use array.sort, but the result will be return like `,,,,,00013345778`

So is there any solution to get my expect result?

This is the code I try to do:

```
String result = 04,07,01,57,83,39;
Sorting(result);

public static string Sorting(string input)
{
    char[] characters = input.ToArray();
    Array.Sort(characters);
    return new string(characters);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is ambiguous whether the original data is a string or an integer.

If it's an integer, @Carlos Jafet Neto's answer would be appropriate.

If it is a character string, it will be as follows.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String result = "04,07,01,57,83,39";
    Console.WriteLine(Sorting(result));
}
public static string Sorting(string input)
{
    string[] characters = input.Split(',');
    Array.Sort(characters);
    return string.Join(',',characters);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
    public static void Main()
{
    int[] arr = new int[] {04,07,01,57,83,39}; 
    Array.Sort(arr);

    foreach(int value in arr) 
    { 
        Console.Write(value + " "); 
    } 
    
}
```

I notice two things you are missing in your code: the brackets in the array declaration as string[ ] or int[ ], and to declare an array literal, the syntax is like this:

```
string[] values = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is a compilation error in your code (string literal should be enclosed in "" like `"this is c# string"`)

Second of all, when you perform `ToArray()` on your string you get back an array of characters which is the following for this string `"01, 02, 03"`: `['0', '1', ',', ' ', '0', '2', ',', ' ', '0', '3']`.

So to sort this string as an array of integers you first should convert it to an array of integers like this:

```
int[] sorted = str.Split(',')
                  .Select(s => int.Parse(s.Trim()))
                  .OrderBy(val => val)
                  .ToArray();
```

Or as correctly noticed @kunif in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65855401/8715436)  you may sort array of strings after `Split` (without parsing in to `int`) if you need get back a `string` rather than an integers array. Notice however that if in your string there are values with different length like 153 and 16, this may lead to incorrect results, because strings are sorted character by character and since `'5'` is less than `'6'`, `"153"` is less than `"16"`. I guess you added leading zeros to your values to prevent this problem from happening. So the right answer actually depends on your needs.